# jquery - positioning of cloned object

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the user hits return while in one of the given text input fields, I'm trying to insert a new, blank text input field right below it - and before the other existing ones. The code below works fine in appending it to the bottom of the container, but I'm struggling with how to place it directly below the selected input field.

Any suggestions?

JS

```
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {

     $(this).clone(true).val('').appendTo('#item_container').focus();
     return false;

}
```

HTML

```
<div id="item_container">   
        <input type="text" class="list_item">
        <input type="text" class="list_item">
                    <input type="text" class="list_item">
                    <input type="text" class="list_item">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) {

     $(this).clone(true).val('').insertAfter(this).focus();
     return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
$(this).after($(this).clone(true).val('')).focus();
```

or [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)

```
$(this).clone(true).val('').insertAfter(this).focus();
```

Comment: Probably the second one since your code is already more like that (: And easier to read in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) or [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter) for that ;)

```
var target = $(this)
var copy = target.clone();
target.after(copy)
copy.val('').focus();
```

or all at once:

```
$(this).after($(this).clone().val('').focus());
```

this sets the **focus** on and clears the **new** element

or

```
$(this).after($(this).clone()).val('').focus();
```

this sets the **focus** on and clears the **old** element

**[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gw4Qy/)**

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a [`:focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) selector which can be used to find the item with focus, i.e.

```
$("#item_container input:focus")
```

Comment: He already has an `event` listener attached to all the inputs so this is not necessary because it is already wrapped in `this`